# How do I limit the number of labels for similar objects in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

[image: example of the problem]

I'd like to reduce the clutter in this map by limiting the spacing or number of times that a particular label can appear. For example, the label 'US 15' should not appear within some set distance another 'US 15' label.

I know why there are so many: QGIS is labeling every feature. I just don't know how to limit it.

Comment: Have you tried the "merge connected lines" option?

Comment: Thanks. That solved most of the issue. I had not seen that option before. Now the only remaining issue is double labels wherever a highway is represented by two parallel lines (such as US 340 in the example).

Comment: merge the two lines into a multipart geometry - use vector -> Geometry tools-> single parts to multipart and join on name

Comment: @DavidPrentiss - for the benefit of later visitors, could you put what worked for you into an answer

Answer (score -2):

[image: Pic11]

I don't know your problem clearly but try to do 03 option in this picture.